# Display adwords stats on intranet dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

My company is requiring me to add our daily spend totals, ctr, conversions in a table on our intranet page.

I was planning on doing this using the Adwords API but the dashboard is done in ASP.NET Core and there is no documentation for that.

Would Google Scripts, which I haven't used, help me pull this data using a JSON call from our website intranet page or is there another solution to avoid using Adwords API?

Is there a simple solution to pull this simple data?

Comment: Adwords API has a bunch of [Client Library support page](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries) and that includes .NET implementation. There is even a plethora of Code Samples in .NET [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/vb/basic-operations)